# Split subfolders of patients into train test folders

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, train-test-split

I have a population of patient MRIs and masked truths of a muscle. I am working on a U-Net segmentation algorithm to automatically segment and determine the size of a muscle. I originally ran all slices of every patient through train test split, however, I realized that the model could potentially train and test on the same patient, leading to data leakage and possibly skewing the accuracy.

For each patient, I have a separate folder containing their slices and masks.

```
PATIENT_FOLDERS
├───01
│       FATFRACTION_01_10_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_11_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_12_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_13_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_14_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_15_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_16_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_17_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_18_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_19_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_20_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_21_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_22_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_23_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_24_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_25_pre.png
│       FATFRACTION_01_9_pre.png
│       psoas_01_10_pre.png
│       psoas_01_11_pre.png
│       psoas_01_12_pre.png
│       psoas_01_13_pre.png
│       psoas_01_14_pre.png
│       psoas_01_15_pre.png
│       psoas_01_16_pre.png
│       psoas_01_17_pre.png
│       psoas_01_18_pre.png
│       psoas_01_19_pre.png
│       psoas_01_20_pre.png
│       psoas_01_21_pre.png
│       psoas_01_22_pre.png
│       psoas_01_23_pre.png
│       psoas_01_24_pre.png
│       psoas_01_25_pre.png
│       psoas_01_9_pre.png
│
└───03
        FATFRACTION_03_25_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_26_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_27_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_28_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_29_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_30_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_31_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_32_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_33_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_34_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_35_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_36_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_37_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_38_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_39_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_40_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_41_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_42_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_43_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_44_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_45_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_46_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_47_pre.png
        FATFRACTION_03_48_pre.png
        psoas_03_25_pre.png
        psoas_03_26_pre.png
        psoas_03_27_pre.png
        psoas_03_28_pre.png
        psoas_03_29_pre.png
        psoas_03_30_pre.png
        psoas_03_31_pre.png
        psoas_03_32_pre.png
        psoas_03_33_pre.png
        psoas_03_34_pre.png
        psoas_03_35_pre.png
        psoas_03_36_pre.png
        psoas_03_37_pre.png
        psoas_03_38_pre.png
        psoas_03_39_pre.png
        psoas_03_40_pre.png
        psoas_03_41_pre.png
        psoas_03_42_pre.png
        psoas_03_43_pre.png
        psoas_03_44_pre.png
        psoas_03_45_pre.png
        psoas_03_46_pre.png
        psoas_03_47_pre.png
        psoas_03_48_pre.png
```

I have tried using splitfolders, however, this only splits the data within the folders, not the folders themselves.

```
splitfolders.ratio(patient_folders, output=preprocessed_dir, seed=1337, ratio=(.8, 0.1,0.1))
```

How can I split the folders/patients into train test groups, not just the individual files? Thank you!

Comment: Last time I wanted to do something similar I didn't find anything relevant online, and I implemented it manually (custom code). But that was 2 years ago.

Comment: Interesting, any chance you can provide the framework of your custom code? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os, shutil
import numpy as np

def split(to, from_, size=0.2, shuffle=True) -> None:
        file = []
        for i in os.listdir(to):
            file.append(os.path.join(to, i))

        if shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(file)

        sizes = int(np.round(float(np.multiply(size, int(len(file))))))
        for i in range(sizes):
            shutil.move(file[int(i)], from_)
```

Your `PATIENT_FOLDERS` have two classes `01` and `03`.

```py
PATH = ""  # Path/Location of your PATIENT_FOLDERS
try:
    os.mkdir("dataset")
    os.mkdir("dataset/train")
    os.mkdir("dataset/test")
    for i in os.listdir():
        os.mkdir(f"dataset/train/{i}")
        os.mkdir(f"dataset/test/{i}")
except FileExistsError:
    pass

for i in os.listdir(PATH):
    split(to=os.path.join(PATH, i), from_=os.path.join(f"dataset/test/{i}"), 
          size=.2, shuffle=True)
```

After, `images` split for your `test` dataset then Again Split for `Training`.

```py
# for i in os.listdir(PATH):
    # split(to=os.path.join(PATH, i), from_=os.path.join(f"dataset/test/{i}"), 
          # size=.2, shuffle=True)

for i in os.listdir(PATH):
    split(to=os.path.join(PATH, i), from_=os.path.join(f"dataset/test/{i}"), 
          size=1, shuffle=True)
```

> `Note :` Don't Split Both with same time.

**I Hope, It will Work Properly.**